# overriding upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to override my `upload_max_filesize` in php but I still get the value which is in my php.ini file which is 2 mb.

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','30M');
ini_set('post_max_size','30M');
echo("<br>".ini_get('upload_max_filesize')."<br>");
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Those settings are not going to have any effect when set via `ini_set`.

The reason is that PHP needs those values *before* your script is even executed. When an upload occurs, the target script is executed when the upload is complete, so PHP needs to know the maximum sizes beforehand.

Set them in `php.ini`, your virtual host config, or in a `.htaccess` file. A typical `.htaccess` file would look like this:

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

Comment: I tried setting it in my .htaccess but no changes took place. I am on a shared hosting. Is it possible to do so??

Comment: how to we add the php value to our code? not direct edit php.ini or .htaccess ?

Comment: This should just be the canonical answer for all questions related to this :P Accurate and lists both the _why_ and _how_.

Comment: Remark regarding the two upper comments: various shared hosts do not allow overriding these settings via `.htaccess`. The restricted settings can normally be found in the FAQ of your hoster or somewhere in the administration section of your hoster's web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '30M');
```

Comment: For completeness, please explain your answer, step by step