# I Cant upload file of size greater than 2 MB on my PHP server , what will be issue

Tags: php, video

I Cant upload file of size greater than 2 MB on my PHP server , what will be issue
can u please help, although in my PHP code i haven't put any limit in my PHP code

Please help
I have used Apache

Thanks in adv

Comment: What HTTP server software are you actually using? IIS? Apache? Lighttpd? Nginx?

Comment: possible duplicate of [overriding upload_max_filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize)

Comment: @JohnP: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The linked question asks how to change `max_upload_filesize`, while this OP is unaware that that directive even exists. They're certainly related, but they're not exact duplicates.

Comment: @BillyONeal I marked it as such because the accepted answer on the question would solve his issue. But you're right, the OP doesn't know where the setting is.

Comment: thanks all now i came to know how to make changes thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default php installation has an upload file size limit of 2MBs. [This](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php) link explains all the details.

In Linux with apache2 you can find this file in:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini OR

/etc/php.ini
```

If none of the above is true for you, look for *Loaded Configuration File* in output of:

```
phpinfo();
```

Comment: Also, change `post_max_size` to be greater than the new value of `upload_max_filesize`. You can find the `php.ini` file in the `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: @Carlos: +1 for giving a generic solution. Though I look at its output quite often for verifying what versions I am running, I never looked for this in that output.

Answer (score 2):

Also check the `LimitRequestBody` directive in Apache config.

Answer (score 1):

PHP.ini contains a setting `upload_max_filesize`. The default value is 2MB. Keep in mind that even where PHP does not limit this value (e.g. if you modify your PHP.ini to a higher level) that your web server software (e.g. Apache, Lighttpd, Nginx, IIS) probably impose their own limits.

Answer (score 1):

Check in php.ini (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini in debian & ubuntu)
directive: `upload_max_filesize`
if can't - look this key in .htaccess file

Comment: Of course, this assumes that you're using Apache in addition to assuming you're using Ubuntu. Plenty of PHP apps run on IIS, Lighttpd, or Nginx.