# Unable to change upload_max_filesize to Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I have a Laravel Azure website.

I have a `.user.ini` file where I have some settings like

```
upload_max_filesize=120M
post_max_size=121M
output_buffering=Off
max_execution_time=3000
max_input_time=3000
memory_limit=140M
```

But, strangely enough, only `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit changed`. I also tried `ini_set()` but with the same result.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing those settings?  I'm not familiar with Azure, but I'm used to restarting Apache after I make an .ini change so it picks it up and takes effect.  Also, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/949428/2635601) you cannot change `upload_max_filesize` during execution of the script.

Comment: I restarted the server, but with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically I added in the settings PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR with the value of the folder path to the .user.ini

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Azure Settings->Configuration
2. Under 'Application settings', Click 'New Application settings' add following:

   Name: PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR

   Value: (whatever path, ex. d:\home\site\ini)
3. Open powershell, Go to Development Tools->Advanced Tools, Click 'Go ->'
4. Open folder on the path you specify on #2 (ex. 'd:\home\site\ini'). Then create `.user.ini` file
5. Add the following:

   upload_max_filesize = 64M

   post_max_size = 64M
6. Restart your server

You may check the values on your server using:

`php -r "echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');"`

`php -r "echo ini_get('post_max_size');"`

Answer (score 0):

As PHP applications on Azure are actually hosted on IIS, so the limit upload file size is not only controlled by PHP settings but also by IIS configurations.

By default, the maximum length of content in a request is set 30000000 in IIS which is approximately 28.6MB. You can refer to https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits#005 for more details.

And beside custom configuration of PHP, you also need to create a `web.config` in your root directory, whose content can be the following sample:

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes (B)  -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this but there was no change for my test of uploading big files.

Comment: What's the size of the file you uploaded?

Comment: It works on files under 30MB. Over 30MB it gives error. This limit does not take into consideration the PHP INI setting.

Comment: it seem that it failed configurations in IIS. The `web.config` file should be put in the root directory of your app, which is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, and after created the file, have you restart the site? Additionally, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/ and leverage IIS Manager to configure the IIS settings.

Comment: I managed to change the settings with the help of this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hosamshobak/archive/2015/03/20/azure-websites-how-to-change-php-ini-settings.aspx . Basically I added in the settings PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR with the value of the folder path to the .user.ini