# How to modify the GET data size limit in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, azure

I use Django, Azure. My js code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/proj/dist/',
    data: {rows0: rows0},
    success:function(json){
```

rows0 length is 1386. It fails and produces AJAX failure.

However it works on local machine. How can I change the size of the limit on Azure server or is there any other solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change upload\_max\_filesize to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594599/unable-to-change-upload-max-filesize-to-azure)

Comment: If the HTTP method is one that cannot have an entity body, such as GET, the data is appended to the URL. If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path, So i would suggest you to check the path length and your URL length.

Comment: What kind of string are you sending? For eg: sending HTML can cause security issue and can therefore be a server side error. Pls add the error in the question.