Unable to upload file more than 2 mb in Azure app service application
I have made a PHP 8.2 application and have hosted on Azure. I am not able to upload any file beyond 2 mb. Any help will be much appreciated. I get error 413- entity too large.
I have tried putting startup.sh and php.ini in root folder whose codes are as follows:-
startup.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "client_max_body_size 5M;" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
service php8.2-fpm restart

php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 5M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 128M

it is still giving the same issue. I tried putting
client_max_body_size 5m;
on the server through ssh but it still the same result.
Tried copying the default folder to home and putting the client max body over there and on the startup command, gave the location to copy the default to the nginx/site-enabled/default and restarting the nginx server but nothing

Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594599/unable-to-change-upload-max-filesize-to-azure

Also see here: https://azureossd.github.io/2016/06/15/uploading-large-files-to-azure-web-apps/

There is documentation available on how to configure this: Configure a PHP app for Azure App Service - Customize-non-PHP_INI_SYSTEM directives.
Next to adding the files in a folder called INI, it involves steps like:

Then, go to the Azure portal and add an Application Setting to scan the "ini" directory that you just created to apply the change for upload_max_filesize.

Go to the Azure portal and select your App Service Linux PHP application.
Select Application Settings for the app.
Under the Application settings section, select + Add new setting.
For the App Setting Name, enter "PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" and for value, enter "/home/site/wwwroot/ini".
Select the save button.


