# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini error while uploading plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

When I tried to upload a plugin for my Wordpress template in **wamp 2.0** I got an error:

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you have the access to php.ini file?

Comment: change the limit (obviously)

Comment: When you said it wamp i assuming you in localhost. Another SO question about file size, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overriding upload\_max\_filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seeing as though you've mentioned WAMP, I'm going to assume you can edit the php.ini file?

If you left click on the WAMP icon in the status bar, select the PHP menu and then click on the php.ini file in that menu. Just open it in Notepad is fine.

Then in Notepad, do a search (CTRL+F) for "upload_max_filesize", and then you can change the value that is set there.

I don't remember what the default is, but for mine, I have it set to "200M" (without the quotes). This means 200mb.

Save the file, close it, and then restart WAMP.

You should then be right to upload your plugin

Comment: Thanks for responding.Unfortunately It was not working for me.So I just placed the plugin in "\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins" now it is working.

Answer (score 12):

We have seen this error at least once if we have used WordPress.When installing a theme, plugin or uploading an image or file, It has nothing to do with the theme or plugin. The issue is with our server settings which limit the maximum size for uploaded files.

It’s a common error and it can be easily fixed. This error message is an indication of that the file you are trying to upload is larger than your web host allows (WordPress default file upload size is 2 MB).

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

**Solution:**

A solution is easy, need to increase the file size upload limit.

If using WordPress on a local machine using XAMPP, we will find the php.ini in the following locations.
**Windows:  C:/xampp/php/php.ini**

Open the php.ini file. Find these lines in the php.ini file and replace it following numbers

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Save the changes and refresh your website and try uploading the file again. You will now get success.

Comment: Note that if you work in MAMP, you should restart your server (on/off), only then will the change become effective!

Answer (score 9):

In Wamp > PHP > php.ini file, put or edit these lines, and then restart your Wamp server.

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000  
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Answer (score 3):

A Solution is easy, you just want to add plugin in your `WordPress`.

1. Download your `.zip` file of plugin.
2. `Extract` the `.zip` file.
3. Now, upload the extracted folder to `../wp-content/plugins/` location.
4. Go to the `Installed Plugins` page in `WordPress`, Now you can see the plugin is there, which you have recently uploaded.
5. Finally, click `activate` link.

Answer (score 3):

This error is because your upload_max_filesize variable in php.ini file is adjusted to 2Mb.. change it to 64Mb!! 
[This video tutorial](https://youtu.be/syrHl9ls8uY) will help you fixing your error in 60 seconds!! Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I use MAMP. To locate the 'php.ini' file, if you also use MAMP, the way Is as follows:

1. Go to the folder location where the MAMP is installed. For example, 'C:\MAMP' Is the folder location of MAMP.
2. Go to 'conf' folder.
3. From 'localhost:8888/MAMP', you will get 'phpinfo' link under PHP section. Click on the link and from the directed page, get the version of PHP is installed into your system.
4. From 'conf' folder, go to the folder with the version of PHP you got in the previous step.
5. Go to that folder and you will get the required php.ini file.
6. Open that file in any text editor and update the info:
   (memory_limit = 64M, upload_max_filesize = 128M, post_max_size = 512M)
7. Restart MAMP.
   Then you are good to go for uploading big files into your local server.

Comment: I am using MAMP too.. Its working.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open your xampp software and click on config button in front of apache option and select php.ini option

Next find this code

```
upload_max_filesize=2M
```

and replace with this code

```
upload_max_filesize=64M
```

Now restart apache and mysql and enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

Find this line in the **php.ini** file `upload_max_filesize = 2M` and replace it with a higher value (e.g. `upload_max_filesize = 64M`)

And restart wamp..!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WAMP 2 you should update to Release 3.2.3.x with the GUI you can set **upload_max_filesize** to 64MB recommended to do so follow the instructions.

1. Click WAMP icon at taskbar
2. Go to PHP
3. PHP Settings
4. Find "upload_max_filesize" and select the size

Answer (score 0):

Locate the php.ini file in your local dir. I use Xampp. =>C:\Xampp. Now find the line where it says

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

and change this to your desired value.

```
upload_max_filesize = 56M
```

Restart all your services and you should be able to upload your new files.

Answer (score 0):

Windows: C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress_project/.htaccess
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
// in end tag of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Amazon ec2 instance and I had installed wordpress. I modified upload_max_filesize directive in /etc/php.ini. Then I tried restarting the httpd service, but that did not solve my issue.

**Rebooting the Amazon ec2 instance solved the issue for me.**

For some reason, restarting the httpd service did not make the server pick the new values. Rebooting the ec2 instance did the trick