# How to fix file exceeds the upload_max_size directive in php.ini

Tags: wordpress

Everyone
When I was installing one plugin in wordpress by uploading then I got an error saying that: `File exceeds the upload_max_size directive in php.ini` Please tell me how I can fix this error. I am using localhost.

Thank in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The uploaded file exceeds the upload\_max\_filesize directive in php.ini error while uploading plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963262/the-uploaded-file-exceeds-the-upload-max-filesize-directive-in-php-ini-error-whi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it you need to edit the `php.in`i file which will be in the `wp-admin` folder
 if you are using live website. You just need to search there.
If you are using `localhost` then find php.ini in your installation directory.

Such as if you are using `xampp` then it will be inside `C:/xampp/php.`
Then just search the word that is bold here and replace with the value after the (=) sign
**memory_limit**  = 256M 
**post_max_size** = 32M
**max_execution_time** = 600
 
**max_input_time** = 900
Hope it will help you