# PHP - Check Size on File Upload

Tags: php

I am uploading a file to database using php. May I know why I am not getting any amount of size when I upload? When I `print_r($_FILES)` on the size it return:

```
Array
(
    [uploaded] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => f2-CP-2016.pdf
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

    [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
```

I have upload a file but the size still return 0. I want to make a validation for `size > 3MB` it will return an error. Below are my codes:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++){
    $array = array($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filesize_upload = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'][$i];

    if($filesize_upload > 3145728){
        die('File is BIG');
    } else {
        //proceed to upload
    }   

}
```

> **Update with error:**

This is the error that I received

```
[error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 4
            )
```

Comment: `echo filesize($tmpFilePath);`

Comment: was the file actually there? no: server may have blocked the upload. is the file size 0 bytes by any chance? no: maybe it was too big? some more information would be splendid.

Comment: error code from $_FILES['uploaded']['error'] is != 0 ?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not in front of my pc at the moment. Will give the update later

Comment: ok. it may be upload_max_filesize from php ini. try to see if is any errors here: $_FILES['uploaded']['error']

Comment: @CatalinB the error is due to upload_max_filesize. Do I need to edit it on the php file?

Comment: try to add `php_value upload_max_filesize 30M` in a .htaccess ... read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/949428/6797531

Comment: I don't have the .htaccess fie. I am using XAMPP. Can I create the file?

Comment: I create the file on my domain folder and it work great. Thank you @CatalinB!

Answer (score 1):

Check the error index in the uploaded array... you might have a code which defines the error nature.

[Read the Error messages](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not in front of my pc at the moment. Will give the update later