# Post request getting null at server side?

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have written PHP web service using **Laravel framework** to upload images using base64 string.
it is working fine for small base64 string. but when I tried to generate base64 string of 5 MB image then it is getting NULL requst at server side.
here is the PHP server side code:

```
<?php
  $post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

  $post_data = json_decode($post_data);
  var_dump($post_data);exit;
 ?>
```

Useing above source code when I tried to print small base 64 request then it is working fine. When I tried to post large base64 image it is returning NULL.

Please help where I am going wrong. Also please suggest is there any other way to upload large base 64 string at server side.

Also I have tried to edit `php.ini` at `"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/conf/php.ini"` with the following value

```
post_max_size 200M
upload_max_filesize 200M
```

and tried to restart sever but still the same error occurs.

Comment: json_decode needs a valid json data to decode, otherwise gives null

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize (post_max_size / upload_max_filesize)

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR not getting large base 64 string. this is the issue.

Comment: change the size of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in the php.ini

Answer (score 3):

You're probably hitting a PHP limit. Check your `php.ini` file for the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings.

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

If you change these values, you'll need to restart PHP.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am using laravel what i need to change there in config

Comment: Notice the post_max_size is the size of ALL post data you send to the server. This mean you can hit the limit with a data which is NOT the big one. Eg you have a limit at 8Mo and you send a picture of 7.9Mo and also, after the image, a text. You'll receive the image correctly and get a NULL for the text. So the NULL came with the variable hitting the limit.