# How to change values in php.ini using php application

Tags: php

Just a quick question. Is there a way to change values in the php.ini using codes on the php page so that the values only change for the particular page?

Comment: There is multiple posts about this problem. Please search by yourself before ask this kind of question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible just use function `ini_set`, like:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: why cant i upload files above 2mb ? i used ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');

Comment: @Raiyu note that NOT EVERY setting can be overridden this way. Some settings are restricted by the web server (e.g. Apache) or by PHP itself.

Comment: @Raiyu Specifically, `upload_max_filesize` can't be overriden via `ini_set`. You can override this value in `.htaccess` if you use Apache. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize

Comment: @AlexShesterov Thank you for your reply. Yes i use apache. is there a way to change the value in .htaccess using the php page?

Comment: You have to set `php_value upload_max_filesize 50M` in .htaccess.

Comment: @Raiyu, at the moment when the PHP script runs, it's already too late to override the `upload_max_filesize` value. So it's not possible to set this value from the PHP script itself. 
What you can do (depending on your permissions / environment): 1. edit `php.ini` file, 2. create/edit the `.htaccess` file, which is next to your root PHP script being executed or, 3. edit main Apache configuration. If nothing works: contact your hosting provider.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Okay i'll try what you just said. Thankyou so much for helping me out.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Just wanted you to know that i created the .htaccess file and typed the lines and i don't understand how but it worked :D. You just saved my day my friend thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should change that in .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

> PHP_INI_PERDIR Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or
>   .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)